# For a local complete intersection ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$ with $\mathfrak m^3=0\ne \mathfrak m^2$, $\mathfrak m$ can be generated by two elements

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings, complete-intersection, syzygies

Let $(R,\mathfrak m,k)$ be a local complete intersection ring with $\mathfrak m^3=0\ne \mathfrak m^2$. As $0\ne \mathfrak m^2 \subseteq \text{soc}(R)$ and $R$ is Gorenstein, so we get $\mathfrak m^2 =\text{soc}(R)\cong k$.

Now according to the beginning of Section 3 in page 293 of https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(85)90016-7, it holds that $\dim_k (\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2)\le 2$. However, no proof or reference to a proof is given. I have seen the same statement appear in other places as well, but again without any proof.
Could someone please outline a proof or provide a reference to a proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The associated graded ring is also a complete intersection.  Its Hilbert series is the product from $i=1,\dots,n$ of $(1-t^{d_i})/(1-t)$, where the $d_i$ are the degrees of the defining equations.  In particular, the socle is in degree $\sum_i (d_i-1)$.  So, if the socle is in degree $2$, then the Hilbert series is either $(1-t^3)/(1-t)$ or $(1+t)^2$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: thank you for your comment, but why is the associated graded ring also a complete intersection? I thought that local complete intersection rings whose associated graded rings are also Complete Intersections, are called "strict complete intersections" . Definitely hypersurfaces are strict complete intersections, but this can fail in codimension $2$ as mentioned in page 2 (after Theorem 1) of https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.10140. Are you saying that Artinian local complete intersection rings with $\mathfrak m^3=0$ are also strict complete intersections?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your notation.  Is $k$ a coefficient field for $R$?

Comment: @JasonStarr: No no, $k$ is just the residue field of the local ring $R$ ..... but let me also ask: If $R$ is a local complete intersection with a coefficient field, then the associated graded ring is also complete Intersection?

Answer (score 2):

I an writing this as an answer.  It is indeed the case that the graded ring of a local Artinian complete intersection ring can fail to be a local Artinian complete intersection ring.  Here is a direct argument instead.

By hypothesis, $R$ is a quotient $A/I$ of a complete local ring $(A,\mathfrak{n},k)$ that is regular, where $I$ is generated by an $A$-regular sequence in $\mathfrak{n}^2$.  In particular, the induced $k$-linear map from $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$ to $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is an isomorphism.  Let $(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ be an ordered $d$-tuple of elements of $\mathfrak{n}$ that map to a $k$-basis for $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$.
Thus, the ideal $I$ is generated by a regular sequence of length $d$ inside $\mathfrak{n}^2$.  Now consider the $d(d+1)/2$ $k$-linearly independent elements $x_ix_j\in \mathfrak{n}^2/\mathfrak{n}^3$.  The $R$-module $\mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3$ equals the quotient of the $A$-module $\mathfrak{n}^2/\mathfrak{n}^3$ by $I/(I\cap \mathfrak{n}^3)$.  Also $I/(I\cap \mathfrak{n}^3)$ is a quotient of $I/I\cdot \mathfrak{n}$, which is a $k$-vector space of dimension $d$.  Thus, the $k$-vector space dimension of $\mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3$ is at least $d(d+1)/2 - d = d(d-1)/2$.

Thus, if the socle of $A$ is $\mathfrak{m}^2$, so that $\mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3$ has $k$-vector space dimension equal to $1$, then either $d=1$ and $I\subset \mathfrak{n}^3$ or $d=2$ and $I\cap \mathfrak{n}^3$ equals $I\cdot \mathfrak{n}$, i.e., the $2$ minimal generators of $I$ are elements of $\mathfrak{n}^2$ whose images in $\mathfrak{n}^2/\mathfrak{n}^3$ are $k$-linearly independent.